# Regex to match three groups of which the last two have fixed lengths

Tags: regex

I have 3 matching groups per line of which I know the latter two one's lengths.
So the last one is a 3 letter code (A-Z), the one before that is a 2 letter code (A-Z) and the first one is a string of unknown length that also has spaces and non latin characters.
My regex can match the last two groups but only grabs the last word of the first matching group:

```
([\p{L}]*)\s*([A-Z]{2})\s*([A-Z]{3})\s*
```

These are the lines:

```
Afghanistan AF AFG
Åland Islands AX ALA
Albania AL ALB
Algeria DZ DZA
American Samoa AS ASM
British Indian Ocean Territory IO IOT
```

If I extend the first matching group to also include spaces, then everything is in that group.

Any hep is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had tried that and it would simply match the whole line in that first group. Who knows where I put that space tho... Maybe add this as answer?

Comment: I removed the previous comment, but you could add a space to `([\p{L} ]*)`  https://regex101.com/r/mGlSaK/1

Comment: You may also use `([\p{L}\s]*?)\s([A-Z]{2})\s*([A-Z]{3})\s*`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sUlHxv/1).

Comment: If the spaces between the characters are always there, you could also use `([\p{L}]+(?: [\p{L}]+)*) ([A-Z]{2}) ([A-Z]{3})\s*`[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGlSaK/2)

Answer (score 1):

You only get the last word because the character class is not matching a space which is between the words.

You could solve that by adding a space to the character class `([\p{L} ]*)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGlSaK/1)

If you only want the words without the last space and the 2 and 3 letter combination are always at the end, you could make the first \s not optional by removing the asterix or use `\s+`:

```
([\p{L} ]*)\s([A-Z]{2})\s*([A-Z]{3})\s*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JrIFOn/1)